# scikit-learn Random Forest excessive memory usage

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm running scikit-learn (version 0.15.2) Random Forest with python 3.4 in windows 7 64-bit. I have this very simple model:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

#Data=np.genfromtxt('C:/Data/Tests/Train.txt', delimiter=',')

print ("nrows = ", Data.shape[0], "ncols = ", Data.shape[1]) 
X=np.float32(Data[:,1:])
Y=np.int16(Data[:,0])
RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000)
RF.fit(X, Y)
```

The X dataset has about 30,000 x 500 elements of the following format:

139.2398242257808,310.7242684642465,...

Even with no parallel processing, the memory usage creeps up to 16 GB eventually! I'm wondering why there is so much memory usage.

I know this has been asked before sometime ago but before the 0.15.2 version...

Any suggestions?

Comment: your estimator parameter is very high and you are not controlling for the depth of the trees.

Comment: Thank you. What would you recommend for the ranges for the depth of of trees and n_estimator for the case of multi-classification of ~100 classes?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the number of estimators and seeing if it reduces the memory used? It is just a guess I'm afraid- I wondered if you were creating lots of very deep trees.

Comment: Yes, it is reducing the memory usage. And with the depth of the trees not set, I guess it was going wild. I have a big dataset with many features and classes and I thought I needed to use many trees. I need to experiment more...

Comment: You can also try to control the depth of the trees by increasing the number of datapoints needed at each split. I think the default is two. Increasing this might allow you to increase the number of estimators.

Comment: Thank you. I will set up a grid search and search for the depth and the n_estimator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing the number of trees by setting a smaller n_estimators parameter. You can then try to control the tree depth using max_depth or min_samples_split and trade of depth for an increased number of estimators.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, memory consumption is linear with the number of classes. Since you have 100s of them and quite a decent number of samples, it is not surprising that memory is blowing up. Solutions include controlling the size of the trees (`max_depth`, `min_samples_leaf`, ...), their numbers (`n_estimators`) or to reduce the number of classes in your problem, if that is possible.

Comment: Thanks. I've experimenting with all of these that you mentioned and the memory issue is OK now. The main culprit was not controlling the depth of the trees.